# OpenSeadragon change images in a collection on the fly

Tags: deepzoom, seadragon

I have a serie of DZI images (a scanned book) that I want to display in OpenSeadragon. If I use the collectionMode, I can set up OpenSeadragon to display two images on one page. But can I dynamically changes those images into other images?

My goal is to display page even and page odd, two at a time, but use their sequence mode to so to speak turn the pages in the book.

If anyone knows about other projects with a comparable aim, I would also appreciate a nudge in here (It seems to me to be quite an obvious need, but I haven't found any projects working on it yet)?

/Hasse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is exactly the sort of scenario that https://github.com/openseadragon/openseadragon/issues/386 is meant to address. It's a big project, though, so it may not be usable for a couple months yet. If you're interested in helping to make it happen, we'd love to have the help! Otherwise, you can subscribe to that issue to keep abreast of the progress.

Comment: That's great news! :)
I'll look into the branch when I get around it. If there is anything I can contribute with (bearing in mind that I am a complete newbie with OpenSeadragon and not particular sharp @ math), I will gladly help!

Comment: Probably the first step is just to get familiar with what's new in that branch... take a look at test/demo/collections/main.js for an example of the new features in use. Perhaps you could give it a try with your own data and give me some feedback on how you would like the API to shape up.

Answer (score 1):

Since I wrote my previous answer, another possibility has shown up. Seajax, a sibling to OpenSeadragon in the Seadragon family tree, has just been released:

https://github.com/seajax/seajax

It already supports custom arrangements of multiple images (though it doesn't yet have much touch support).

Comment: That looks awesome! By far the most sexy pivot table I have ever seen! But it does not look like it is aimed directly at my needs (the book pages), so I think I'm gonna stick with OpenSeadragon anyway. But thanks for the link - it's definitely a great source of inspiration! :)